# Magento order tax information

Tags: magento, tax

I see that tax information is kept at order level but I cannot see any setters/getters for it.

It could be related with Quote Items or even with Shipping addresses?

Anybody knows how tax is related to order?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are fields on the sales_order table for taxes after they've been calculated:

```
| tax_refunded                | decimal(12,4)
| tax_canceled                | decimal(12,4)
| base_tax_refunded           | decimal(12,4)
| base_tax_canceled           | decimal(12,4)
| tax_invoiced                | decimal(12,4)
| base_tax_invoiced           | decimal(12,4)
| shipping_tax_amount         | decimal(12,4)
| base_shipping_tax_amount    | decimal(12,4)
| shipping_tax_refunded       | decimal(12,4)
| base_shipping_tax_refunded  | decimal(12,4)
```

When you have an order object, you can use the normal Magento getters to obtain this data. E.g.

```
$taxRefunded = $order->getTaxRefunded();
```

Hope that helps.

Thanks,
Joe